# method in Vue.js cannot alter data value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js 2 and i'm trying to make a component that does a simple discount calculation after user input.

The object i'm using as starting data is an object made like this: it is composed of several building and each of them can have several rooms inside. I have an object (i write it as an array, but it's an object) who has

```
buildings[<building_id>][<room_id]={room_id: <room_id>,
                                    building_id: <building_id>
                                    name: <name>,
                                    price: <regular_price>
                                    discounted_price: <discounted_price>
                                    discount: discount}
```

Here is the full code of the component

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ buildings }}
        <li v-for="(building, k) in buildings" :key="k">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th>Room</th><th>Standard price</th><th>Discounted price</th><th>Discount</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(room, s) in building" :key="s">
                        <td>{{room.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{room.price}} €</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="room.discounted_price" 
                            @input="calcDiscount(room)"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="room.discount" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            buildings: {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getBuildings();
    },
    methods: {
        getBuildings: function(callback) {
            httpRequest(api_url + "get/buildings").then(onResult => {
                this.buildings = onResult.data.buildings;
            });
        },
        calcDiscount(evt) {
            room.discount = Math.round(
               100 - (100 * room.discounted_price) / room.price
            );
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have two problems with this code. First, the v-bind on the input element does not work. As you can see i've printed the `buildings` object on top and i don't see the values of `discounted_price` change on the user input.

But apart this, despite the log display the right values, nor the value of `discount` nor of `discounted_price` are changed in the object. But the values are taken correctly because they're printed right just one line before. What i'm doing wrong? Thanks

EDITED after tao comments

FURTHER UPDATE: Since the code tao made [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-agnesi-j1vf4?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) in the playground works, the problem should be something in my environment. Apparently the function `calcDiscount` works well since if i print the value inside that function it's printed correctly. But somehow the changes disappear when function exists. Could be that the event take place like in a different space?

Comment: Could you create a *runnable* [mcve]? Use a stack snippet, codesandbox.io or any similar service. Debugging code that can't be run is nearly impossible. And making assumptions about your code is not good, either, as there's no guarantee a potential solution might actually work. At least provide some sample data. What you're showing is invalid syntax.

Comment: Had a closer look, there are plenty of things wrong with your code. But what's probably blocking you right now is you're trying to use [`v-bind`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) instead of [`v-model`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html). See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-agnesi-j1vf4?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue). Another big no-no is querying the dom for values. Vue is data-driven, you already have all the data available, no need to search for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as you can imagine this is just a piece of code from a much bigger project, it's not easy to translate and obfuscate original data. I've corrected `v-model` thanks, but it's not affecting the problem: still the variables don't bind. I'm trying to build up a runnable example on code pen. It's not that easy

Comment: Not sure what's more difficult: for you to build a repro or for me to fix it without repro. Take your time. Also note I've updated that link with a bit of cleanup :)

Comment: That's wonderful. Your code works. Apart the `v-model` and the calculation, it seems you haven't changed anything. Despite this my original code still doesn't make the bind.... so the error should be somewhere else

Comment: My best guess is that in your original code there is actually a reference error of some sort after the console.log which prevents the assignments from executing. Have you double-checked your console for any suspicious errors? Can you single step across those assignments successfully in a debugger?

Comment: No error, nor warning, nor nothing else comes out in the console. I've used tao code for the calculation of discount and made: `console.log('disc'+room.discount);` in `calcDiscount` function and the discount is printed correctly on console, so variable is passed correctly. But original `buildings` object does not update. There could be something that could prevent it from udpating?

Comment: Ok, further notice. I've single stepped in debugger and it turns out my component in instanced 2 times in vue memory one with `?72fe` after the name, the second one with `cf43`. In the second one, that is not the original, the function is written differently `_vm.calcDiscount(room)` and in this second component the local variable `room` is instanced, but the general `this.buildings` is not, the watch says `<not available>`. Don't know it that's normal for vue

Comment: Based on xp, that sounds like you should stop and reserve. If you still can't figure it out, your best bet is reproducing in a sandbox. Copy/paste the data coming from server (or a structurally relevant chunk) and all the code of the component (except the fetching part) and it should repro. There's no way we can figure it out without seeing it. What you've shown works (with the already suggested fixes).

Comment: Ok, found it, code was right. In my particular case had to make a forceUpdate to refresh the changes. So @tao  if you like it you can transform your comment in an answer and i'll mark it as solved. Thanks all

Comment: The way it's currently formulated, your question is unlikely to help someone else which, technically, goes against [SO] recommendations around [ask] and [answer]. Glad I could help you out and that you found the cause. Be safe.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `@input` by `v-on:keyup`. input binding just change the value inside but it doesn't make web app recognize that it need to re-render.